# "The key doesn't work" vs. "The key is not working"

Tags: differences, present-tense, progressive-aspect, nuance

Here's a situation. You go to your hotel room and the key that you have is not working. When you go back to the reception, should you say:

> The key is not working, can you fix it.

Or

> The key doesn't work, can you fix it.

**The key is a card and the key used to work.**

Comment: Either one works.

Comment: @tchrist: It's not obvious to me that *any* of the answers on that question address OP's specific point here. Certainly not the overwhelmingly top-rated one. I'd rather see this on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) in the first place, but I don't think pointing to that somewhat superficial set of summations of tense usages is the way to treat it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include why you are confused about which phrasing to use. It's not clear why you think one or both of these is incorrect.

Comment: @tchrist: Enough already! I'm not going to wade through all those to see if one happens to flag up the fine distinction made by John here (which may well not be the *only* possible nuance that could apply). Seriously, I am slightly gobsmacked by your ability to find all those (is it down to the fact that you personally have been painstakingly flagging such questions with the [progressive-aspect](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/progressive-aspect) tag?

Comment: @tchrist: You forgot to include the *oppressively constant and unrelenting* nuance of *"They will **be continuing** to do this forever"*. :)

Comment: @tchrist: We already have an excellent "canonical post" on the [*perfect aspect*](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/) over on ELL. I don't suppose there's any chance you'd do a similar job on the *progressive aspect* there? I know it's a bit sad, but I really get quite a buzz out of being able to redirect/closevote in favour of such "all-embracing" answers (which can always be honed to even greater perfection and progressiveness if the later querant says *"Yeah, but it doesn't specifically address **my** problem"* :)

Answer (score 2):

Saying

- *The key doesn't work*

is making a claim about the key + lock combination, viz. it's broken.

In contrast, saying

- *The key isn't working*

is merely commenting on the present situation, and noting one failure point.
Which may not be related to the key, but to your use of it.

If you're asking for a new key, the first is appropriate, though the second will work, too.
If, on the other hand, you just want somebody to fix it for you (or maybe show you how it works),
the second one is more open-ended and doesn't appear to be demanding or demeaning.

Comment: Dunno about you, but I often find you get a more sympathetic response if you go the complete *opposite* of the potentially aggressive *"Your equipment is faulty"* implications of your first alternative. Just say *"I can't get this key to work"* (or even *"I can't work this key"*), and let *them* figure out where exactly the problem lies. They'll usually start by assuming you just don't *know how* to work it (which is always possible), but then if it *is* faulty, they've probably effectively already taken "ownership" of the problem, which is all you really wanted anyway.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought I was recommending. I musta been too subtle again. Certainly the OP was too subtle for the PtB.

Comment: Hardly! When you explicitly point it out, I can easily see that your #2 is more "general", and thus less confrontational, which is what allowed me to extrapolate an alternative phrasing even further in that direction. But I wasn't consciously aware of such a subtle distinction before seeing your answer, despite having given at least *some* thought to the matter of potential usage distinctions earlier.

Comment: This is at least "close" to the matter of using subtle "persuasion" techniques in our choice of phrasing. I don't have your specialist knowledge in this area, but I sure as hell want to know about things that might influence my thinking without me necessarily noticing them. (Not to mention the possibility of me being able to influence *others* more insidiously! :)

Comment: Oh, then you might enjoy reading about [Pragmatics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmatics). My analysis was a pragmatic one, based on [Politeness Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness_theory).

Comment: I will indeed - thanks for the link. I didn't realise such things were so "formally" studied, but as we now live in a world where it makes a lot of sense for Westerners to get up to speed with what often seems like more advanced *implementation* of "politeness" in many Far Eastern nations, I suppose I shouldn't have been surprised to learn it's attracting professional interest.

Comment: Levinson's _Pragmatics_ is still the gold standard, and Levinson and Brown's _Politeness_ was the pioneering study.

Comment: I at least knew *of* Levinson, and would probably have paired up the title *Pragmatics* with him. But I thought it was more about how "real-world knowledge" influences the meanings of utterances. I certainly didn't realise there was so much more formal treatment of stuff that used to be on the same shelf as "self-help" books like [*How to Win Friends and Influence People*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Win_Friends_and_Influence_People). Which I'm guessing has a chapter on *How to speak to people you want to influence*, though I've never read it.

Comment: The idea is to correlate behavior and language, and provide a good model for the correlation. Carnegie was a gifted amateur, but his books are essentially Ponzi schemes; if you wanna teach people for money how to w.f.&.i.f, he's the gold standard. But if you wanna apply it to your understanding of language and culture, formal accountings are available. Not all of them work, mind; like any scientific theory, there are a lot of outliers. But Levinson's works are really really thorough.

Comment: I took a step back when [the first copy of *Pragmatics* I found on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B00E32NVIY/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new) turned out to cost $100 + p&p. But I found one on eBay for less than a tenth of that, so I'm sold - or rather, *it's* sold (to me).